# PHP exec('git') failing

Tags: php, git, apache, exec

Specifically, I'm trying to get [ViewGit](http://viewgit.fealdia.org/) working on a PHP/Apache/Windows installation.

It seems that PHP is unable to run `exec('git');`.

`exec('whoami');` works just fine, so it isn't a problem with `exec()` being disabled.

Apache is running under it's own user account- if I log in as this user and attempt to run `git` on the command line I get the expected results. The account also has full permissions to do everything with the /Program Files/Git folder.

If I run `exec('git');` on my local machine it works fine, but just won't work on the server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this by upgrading from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.4. Not sure what the issue was, but that has resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

When you type 'git' in command-line on Windows, it opens **git.cmd**. In typical msysgit installation on Windows, **git.cmd** is in PATH, but git.exe may not be!
So, you can try one of below:

- Create a `git.bat` in Windows folder with following contents:
  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe` (check path)
- Add git's bin directory also in Windows PATH. (You can do so by editing system environmental variables)

Comment: Thanks, but I've got `Git/bin` and `Git/cmd` both in my PATH.

Comment: Then check if git.cmd is taking precedence. Eitherways, check by adding git.bat